# File_get_contents(): failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

I am trying to download a previously uploaded file, form database and uploads folder in php codeigniter. I am using code below but downloading empty file.

controller.php

```
  public function downloadFile($incidents_id)
  {
  
   $file = $this->incidents_model->getfile($incidents_id);
  //echo $file; die;
  $this->load->helper('download');
  $path = file_get_contents(base_url()."uploads/".$file); //(the error shows on this line)
 // echo $path; die;
  $name = $file; // new name for your file
  // echo $name ; die;
   force_download($name, $path); // start download`
  
   }
```

incidents_model.php

```
 function getfile($Incident_id )
 {
   $file = $this->db->select('file');
           $this->db->from('incidents');
           $this->db->where('incidents_id' , $Incident_id );
   $query =  $this->db->get();
  //  return $query->row();
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
     return $query->row()->file;
 }
 return false;
  
 }
```

view.php

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <a href="<?=base_url('admin/incidents/downloadFile/' .$incidents->incidents_id)?>">Download file </a>
 </div>
```

so running this code download an empty file.

> echo $file; die;  displays the file name which been saved in db and in uploads folder

> echo $path; die; generates an error:
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:
> file_get_contents(http://localhost:8080/ticketing_tool_v2/uploads/Screenshot
> 2021-03-04 at 5.59.38 PM.png): failed to open stream: Connection
> refused
>
> Filename: admin/Incidents.php
>
> Line Number: 380

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not read the file directly from the disk?

Comment: what you mean by reading from disk?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/ticketing_tool_v2/uploads/Screenshot 2021-03-04 at 5.59.38 PM.png` triggers a download from another URL, over HTTP. If your files lie on the same filesystem, rather open them directly

Comment: I have tried it, it produce the same error

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the documentation for `file_get_contents` you'll observe there's many different ways you can use it. For your purposes you would need to allow inbound connections to the filesystem.

The other way you could do this for better future proofing is to use the CodeIgniter file helper - https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/file_helper.html

Comment: Hello can you help me how to allow inbound connections to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Before reading the file from path, please check whether a path points to a valid file.

```
public function downloadFile($incidents_id) {

try {
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $file = $this->incidents_model->getfile($incidents_id);
     
    $data = file_get_contents(base_url("uploads/" . $file));

    $name = $file; // new name for your file
        
    force_download($name, $data); // start download`
     
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //exception handling code goes here
    print_r($e);
}

}
```

Comment: I have run your code and getting following error:  'A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: name

Filename: admin/Incidents.php

Line Number: 404

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin/Incidents.php
Line: 404
Function: _error_handler

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: Exception Object ( [message:protected] => The file does not exist on path http://localhost:8080/ticketing_tool_v2/uploads/mpdf.pdf [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] =>

Comment: /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin/Incidents.php [line:protected] => 404 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/system/core/CodeIgniter.php [line] => 532 [function] => downloadFile [class] => Incidents [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => 64 ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/index.php [line] => 315 [args] => Array ( [0] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/system/core/CodeIgniter.php ) [function] => require_once ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => )

Comment: Sorry, i have updated my code, Please check now. And for Exception Object ( [message:protected] => The file does not exist on path --- Please check the file exists on the uploads folder or give the right permission to the uploads folder path and its contents

Comment: so this what I get with your code:    Exception Object ( [message:protected] => The file 1615847175_timetable.png does not exist on path http://localhost:8080/ticketing_tool_v2/uploads/1615847175_timetable.png [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin/Incidents.php [line:protected] => 404 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array

Comment: ( [file] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/system/core/CodeIgniter.php [line] => 532 [function] => downloadFile [class] => Incidents [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => 66 ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/index.php [line] => 315 [args] => Array ( [0] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/system/core/CodeIgniter.php ) [function] => require_once ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => )

Comment: Exception Object ( [message:protected] => The file 1615966788_MAEDEH-SOLHJOO_02.xlsx does not exist on path http://localhost:8080/ticketing_tool_v2/uploads/1615966788_MAEDEH-SOLHJOO_02.xlsx [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 0 [file:protected]

Comment: => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin/Incidents.php [line:protected] => 489 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/system/core/CodeIgniter.php [line] => 532 [function] => downloadFile [class] => Incidents [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => 75 ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/index.php [line] => 315 [args] => Array ( [0] => /opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/system/core/CodeIgniter.php ) [function] => require_once ) ) [previous:Exception:private] => )

Comment: so event hough the file is exists in uploads folder but still I get the above message

Comment: Hi Roxana, for debugging can you try with relative path instead of base_url(), if the file resides in your local server.